# How to use unity-container interception in asp.net-core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unity-container, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

If I try to use unity interception within a asp.net-core webapi my call-handlers are never getting called. I know it works in .net-core console applications, in non core applications and even tests in the same project that do not have the webapi stuff around (resolving services from a test container).

Here is the (relevant) code I use to setup the api:

In `Program.cs`:

```
.UseUnityServiceProvider()
```

In `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container) {
    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
    container.RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>().Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor<IProjectService>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.AddControllersAsServices();
    ...
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider` set by `UseUnityServiceProvider()` resolving the types in a way interception is not kicking in.

So what do I need to do to get interception working as it should be? Or is this a known bug somewhere?

[Update]

@Albert: Do you mean something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>(new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()); // new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>()
```

Even when I add the InterfaceInterceptor as second parameter it does not change anything.

Some more info on the HandlerAttribute and CallHandler I use for testing purposes:

```
public class DummyLoggingAttribute : HandlerAttribute {
    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container) 
        return new DummyLoggerCallHandler(){Order = 2};
    }
}

public class DummyLoggerCallHandler : ICallHandler{
    private int _order;

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext) {
        Console.WriteLine("log vor ");

        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);

        Console.WriteLine("log danach ");
        return result;
    }

    public int Order {
        get { return _order; }
        set { _order = value; }
    }
}
```

Applied to a method as follows.

```
[DummyLogging]
public virtual IList<Project> GetAllProjects() {
    return _projectDao.GetAll();
}
```

It even does not make any differences if I add the Attribute to the interface, the implementation or both.

I another .net-core console application I can even successfully use the following extension to automatically configure each registering type for interception.

```
/// <summary>
///     Extension für das automatische Intercepten von Methoden
/// </summary>
public class InterceptionExtension : UnityContainerExtension {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Entfernt die Extension
    /// </summary>
    public override void Remove() {
        Context.Registering -= OnRegister;
        Context.RegisteringInstance -= OnRegisterInstance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialisiert die Extension
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize() {
        Container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        Context.Registering += OnRegister;
        Context.RegisteringInstance += OnRegisterInstance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Event wenn ein Type Registriert wird
    /// </summary>
    private void OnRegister(object sender, RegisterEventArgs e) {
        if (e.TypeFrom != null) {
            Container.Configure<Interception>()
                    .SetInterceptorFor(e.TypeFrom, new InterfaceInterceptor());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Event wenn eine Instance Regestriert wird
    /// </summary>
    private void OnRegisterInstance(object sender, RegisterInstanceEventArgs e) {
        Container.Configure<Interception>()
                .SetInterceptorFor(e.RegisteredType, new InterfaceInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Which leads me to the assumption that it is not a problem with registering interception but resolving services through `UnityServiceProvider`.

Comment: As I understand you need to specify `IInterceptionBehavior`. Do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is an answer to the question.
As I understand the original issue is that the proxy class that must intercept method calls of `ProjectService` is not being created.
I was able to fix it by creation a class derived from `IInterceptionBehavior` and a little bit different type registration.

**MyInterceptionBehavior:**

```
public class MyInterceptionBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public bool WillExecute
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        Console.WriteLine("Interception Called");
        return result;
    }

}
```

And in `ConfigureContainer()` replace your `IProjectService` registration with this:

```
container.RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>(
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<MyInterceptionBehavior>());
```

`Invoke` method is called every time when every method of `IProjectService` is called. I hope this will give you some idea or helps to make work you interception behavior.

Comment: Sorry sir, but it makes things even worse. Now even the text case running without problems before ignores the interception.

Difference between test case and web api:

- web api uses service provider to get an instance of the service

- test case directly calls `container.Resolve<IProjectService>()`

Comment: @debgz, Did you try to replace `MyInterceptionBehavior` with `PolicyInjectionBehavior`?

Comment: Yes, tried that before. But it does not change anything.